# Activity transition animations don't work

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm currently working on a dark theme transition by restarting the activity, but I stumbled upon a problem: the transitions don't work and I have no idea why.

The code below is the theme resources I currently use:

```
    <style name="Theme.TestApp" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
        <!-- Primary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/grey_light</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryVariant">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="colorOnPrimary">@color/on_primary_light</item>
        <!-- Secondary brand color. -->
        <item name="colorSecondary">@color/teal_200</item>
        <item name="colorSecondaryVariant">@color/teal_700</item>
        <item name="colorOnSecondary">@color/white</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="android:statusBarColor">@color/bar</item>
        <item name="background">@color/grey_light</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/list_text</item>
        <item name="android:windowSplashScreenBackground" tools:targetApi="s">@color/primary_light</item>
        <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/WindowAnimation</item>
    </style>

    <style name="WindowAnimation">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@android:anim/fade_in</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@android:anim/fade_out</item>
    </style>
```

And this is the code I use to restart the activity:

```
        myswitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                if (isChecked) {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                    restart();
                }else {
                    AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                    restart();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    public void restart () {
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Settings.class);
        startActivity(i);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently, creating my own animations solved my problem.

fade_in.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```

fade_out.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <alpha
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:toAlpha="0.0"
    android:duration="500" />
</set>
```